# How can I keep active subnav visible when using fadeIn fadeOut for hover states

Tags: jquery, menu, fadein, fadeout, nav

I'm stuck on some jquery, where I have fadeIn and fadeOut on hover states for sub-nav.

Where I'm falling short is once you hover on/off the active state, the sub-nav fades out, but I want it to stay visible.

The jquery:

```
$("ul#main-nav li").hover(function() { //Hover over event on list item
$(this).find("span").fadeIn("slow"); //Show the subnav
    } , function() { //on hover out...
$(this).find("span").fadeOut("slow"); //Hide the subnav
```

I have my code on JF here:

http://jsfiddle.net/ByteMyPixel/g8W5Y/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Drop out of the fade-out if it is the active item:

```
$("ul#main-nav li").hover(function() { //Hover over event on list item
    $(this).find("span").fadeIn("slow"); //Show the subnav
}, function() { //on hover out...
    if($(this).hasClass('active')) {
          return;   
    }
    $(this).find("span").fadeOut("slow"); //Hide the subnav
});
```

Comment: That was perfectly what I needed!  Thank you Diodeus!